# Python append to array vs replace array of zeros

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In Python, when calculating something in a for loop, it is possible to either append the solution from each iteration to a list, eg.

```
import numpy as np

steps = 100
x_list = np.linspace(0,2.0,steps)

y_list = []

for x in x_list:

    # perform calculations, iterating over values in x_list
    # final solution is z:
    #z = ...

    y_list.append(z)
```

or create an array of zeros and replace each zero with the solution from each iteration, eg.

```
import numpy as np

steps = 100
x_list = np.linspace(0,2.0,steps)

y_list = np.zeros(steps)

for x in x_list:

    # perform calculations, iterating over values in x_list
    # final solution is z:
    #z = ...

    y_list[x] = z
```

In general, which method is more efficient or "Pythonic"? Or does it really depend on the calculation inside the for loop itself?

Comment: I'd say neither is most "pythonic"; I'd write either `y_list = [calc(v) for v in x_list]` or `y_list = map(calc, x_list)` (py2).  In any case, worrying about efficiency here is... well, inefficient.  The differences in performance between all of these things is miniscule.

Comment: What do your own time tests show?  Keep in mind that your 2 methods produce different things.  The first is a list, the second is an array.

Comment: It is best to avoid iteration entirely.  Perform your calculations on all of `xlist` at once using existing `numpy` vector functions.  Look up the many SO questions about 'vectorizing'.

Answer (score 2):

I would say none (or both).

More "pythonic" solution (and also more, let say, "programathic") is to write function that does the calculation and use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
def calculator( x ):
    """calculation"""
    return result

y_list = [calculator(x) for x in x_list]
```

Comment: A list comprehension is more compact than an explicit for loop, but not always better.  And not much faster.  But for numeric arrays, initializing the empty array and filling it is a valid option if you must iterate.